# Short story where a criminal is on trial in a locked room, and awaiting execution if found guilty

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for the name of a short sci-fi story. It is about a man locked in a room while he is on trial for murder, awaiting the verdict. If he is found guilty, he will be executed, but he does not know how he will be executed. The story has him thinking of all the ways that the room might kill him, and the steps he takes to avoid it.

At the end of the story, he is told that he has been found not guilty. He is surprised (as he knew he was guilty) but relieved.

> As he touches the door handle to exit the room, he is electrocuted (I think) and killed instantly. In reality, he had been found guilty, and this was the mechanism of execution.

It was a great short story, and I would love to read it again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The doorknob injects him with a fast-acting poison, to kill him humanely. I too have read this story, before 2000 I think, am trying to remember more.

Comment: Some thematic similarities to an imprisonment in *Rise of Endymion*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly a duplicate of this question: [Sci Fi Capital Punishment Story With Execution by Apartment Deathtrap](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169974/sci-fi-capital-punishment-story-with-execution-by-apartment-deathtrap)

The accepted answer there is:

This appears to be ["In The Hereafter Hilton"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64060) by Bob Shaw, first appearing in Omni Magazine in 1980, although if you read it in a collection of stories by multiple authors it was probably in "The Best of Omni Science Fiction No. 5"

It begins with the main character, Renfrew, being installed into the apartment:

> The apartment was neat, stylish, and comfortable— not at all like a machine designed for killing people.
>
> For a few seconds after the entrance door had locked itself behind him, Renfrew stood perfectly still, taking stock of the place, trying to identify the most likely sources of death, The kitchen — always the most complicated room in any habitat — was one area that obviously had to be avoided- Every particle of food and drop of liquid was suspect in case poisons had been administered; the appliances could have been wired in such a way as to electrocute the unwary user, and the bright-lettered canisters could be bombs that would explode on removal of their lids. Even the simple act of opening a cupboard door might release a cloud of instant-acting gas

And of course, ends how you remember:

> The breath left his body in a noisy, quavering sob He pushed a hank of hair away from his forehead, as if giving himself a better view of the glowing words might change their import. The message remained the same. He was a free man!
>
> Renfrew got to his feet, suddenly conscious of how much he had been dreading the ordeal that had lain ahead. He took a last look at the apartment, gave a low chuckle of relief, then strode to the door with a buoyant tread, keyed up for his first taste of liberty in many months.
>
> The doorknob did not turn when he grasped it.
>
> Instead it fired a cloud of poison through the skin of Renfrew's palm, a poison so swift-acting that he had no time to realize he had been tricked by executioners who, in their determination to be humane, were not above telling a little white lie.

You can read the full story [here](http://www.williamflew.com/omni24b.html).